# Is additional voltage required to turn 5 V into -5 V?

Tags: voltage

I was wondering how much additional voltage is required to turn a positive-voltage signal into a negative-voltage signal. For instance, if I send a signal of 5 V and then want to send a signal of -5 V, what additional circuitry is required (like a "switch" of some kind) and how much additional voltage (exceeding the original 5 V) would be required for that circuitry to "signal" that the voltage is negative? I just need to know whether I can get away with 5 V of power for both of the signals or not, or if I would need some more power.

Comment: how much current is required?

Comment: @jsotola, frankly, I don't know. You could elaborate in your answer if the current is the deciding "factor" here. Thanks

Comment: This is highly dependent on the details such as whether the signal is digital or analog and the current you expect to need to provide. Provide as much information as possible. Also, there are two things here: Controlling a -5V output using a +5V input, and producing a -5V source with which to power that -5V output. You can generate -5V from +5V but it's not what I would call "basic" and how you go about it depends a lot on the aformentioned details..  You can also introduce a second isolated 5V source and use that as -5V (such as a battery).

Comment: It would help if you told us what circuit/device you are sending the +/- 5V signal to.

Comment: @DKNguyen, both kinds of signals are needed, positive and negative, but the source for them is the same, although I'm not sure what exactly the source could be. Sorry to drop all of these details, I simply don't know. I was interested in the concept, I lack the details, unfortunately.

Comment: @bp2017 The way electronics tends to work is you break things to blocks to simplify things. In this case, that is the -5V source and the "switch" (for digital) or the "amplifier" or "modulator" (for analog) which controls the connection between the -5V source and load. You certainly can construct a power supply that produces -5V from a +5V input. And if you to produce a signal that can produce an output that swings from +5V to -5V, you take a +5V and -5V source and hook both them to the load each through their own switch/amplifier and control the switch/amplifier in a complimentary style

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How much additional voltage is required to turn a positive-voltage signal into a negative voltage signal?

No additional voltage is required if you use something like a voltage inverter or an inverting buck boost converter.  The conversion will not be 100% efficient, but the extra energy will be supplied in the form of additional current, not additional voltage.

For example, a simple switched capacitor inverter:

[image]

Will take +5V and give you -5V out.  The process is about 70% efficient, so if you want to supply 100mA, you will need to give the converter about 100/0.7 =  143mA.

See:  https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/products/power/charge-pumps/MAX889.html

> frankly, I don't know [current required]. You could elaborate in your answer if the current is the deciding "factor" here.

The amount of current required will determine what type of converter you should use.  Very low current vs high power converters will be designed quite differently.

Comment: But higher mA means more power is required, right?

Comment: @bp2017 Yes, the efficiency being less than 100% means that you must supply additional power.